# Can i restrict data between staff user in same model?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I'm new in Django.I have to create staff user but distinct data between them of same model in django-admin.

Can i add new permission in User model and implement in default admin?

I have not idea about how to implement. i.e. i have 2 staff user, and add data in same model.
If staff-user-1 is login then show only his added data only (can not see data added by staff-user-2).

is possible in built-in django admin ?

Thanks!!!